# Is there any Anypoint Studio Licensed Version?

Tags: mule, mulesoft

Is there a licensed version of Anypoint Studio that Mulesoft customers need to purchase ?

Does the free version that we get not connect with Anypoint Platform with customer domain ?

I am having issue with the latest version of Studio where it gives SSL handshake error when connecting to exchange.

Comment: See [mulesoft's info here](https://www.mulesoft.com/anypoint-pricing) ... At the bottom of that info, there is a link to ask an expert where you can email for information about specific needs such as what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single type of release of Anypoint Studio, ie there is no enterprise version with different features. If you are having problems connecting it to Anypoint Platform it may be a problem with your network infrastructure or installation, not on topic for Stackoverflow.